# Angular: Pull value from localStorage and display values

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, default-selected

I am populating a list in localStorage using a multi select mat-button-toggle-group, but when I try to display the value on my page it comes back empty. What am I missing?

---

I have a mat-button-toggle-group with a (change) trigger and default values **[(value)]="productCookie"**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" name="productSelect" aria-label="Font Style" multiple [(value)]="productCookie (change)=productFilter(group.value)>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.name">
      <a>{{product.name}}</a>
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

which sets the value in localStorage on change **(change)=productFilter(group.value)**

```
productFilter($event){
  console.log("productFilter event value: " + $event)
  this.selectedProductFilter = $event

  // Testing
  console.log(this.selectedProductFilter)
  
  localStorage.setItem('productFilter', JSON.stringify(this.selectedProductFilter));
}
```

**Console Output** after selecting 3 options:

```
productFilter event value: Wii,Xbox,Playstation3
gaming-report.component.ts:280 (3) ["Wii", "Xbox", "Playstation3"]
```

I can then verify through console -> application -> Local Storage that the values have been set

```
productFilter   ["Wii", "Xbox", "Playstation3"]
```

---

So now I try to pull these values:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getProductCookie();
}



getProductCookie(){
 if (localStorage.getItem('productFilter') === null){
  console.log("No filters found in localStorage")  
 }
 else{
  this.productCookie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productFilter'));
  console.log("localStorage Data Type: " + typeof this.productCookie)  //object      
  console.log("localStorage: " + this.productCookie)  // Wii,Xbox,Playstation3

 }  
}
```

**Console Output**:

```
localStorage Data Type: object
localStorage: Wii,Xbox,Playstation3
```

The value is being pulled, and stored in this.productCookie, so I should be able to use productCookie in my html

```
<div>
    testing:
    {{productCookie|json}}
</div>
```

but it doesn't display anything
[productCookie value is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JKUz.png)

Edit: Changed {{productCookie}} to {{productCookie|json}}
now its printing

```
testing: []
```

until I start selecting options
[Selecting an option updates productCookie value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WecUL.png)

Edit: now this prints

```
testing: [ "Wii", "Xbox", "Playstation3" ]
```

---

What am I doing wrong that's preventing this localStorage value from being displayed in the html?

Comment: this.productCookie = localStorage.getItem('productFilter').split(','); Should give you a broken array really. Why did you copy out the correct way (JSON.parse)?

Comment: I have been taking different approaches trying to get it to work.

I changed it back to `this.productCookie = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productFilter'));`

but I'm not seeing any improvement other than this.productCookie not being in brackets anymore. 

localStorage Data Type: object
gaming-report.component.ts:270 localStorage: Wii,Xbox

Comment: Because of the spilt you’re doing, you are converting the string from localStorage to an array (which is type object). Using JSON.parse is the correct approach. So your issue is still you are not seeing the value? You see nothing at all? Or something like [object Object]? If so use {{productCookie | json}} in your template..

Comment: Correct, still no value being displayed (which I'm only using for testing)
End goal is to use the localStorage 'productFilter' value to set the default selections for my button-toggle-group, thus [(value)]="productCookie"


I tried using {{productCookie|json}} just to see if that'd work, but its still showing as an empty value

`testing: []`

Comment: Weird..from the code you’ve shown this should work fine unless I’m missing something obvious? iIs your component set to onPush by any chance?

Comment: Yeah I haven't been able to find any reason as to why I can print productCookie to console, but not the template.

I'm not familiar with onPush, but I didn't find ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in my component.

Comment: From the updates it sounds it is displaying now..? Right?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there are 2 screenshots at the end (on load, and after I select an option from my button list)

On page load: `testing: []`
On selecting options: `testing: [ "Wii", "Xbox", "Playstation3" ]`
reload page and its back to being empty

Comment: Not sure what is going on. Maybe create a stackblitz to reproduce?

Comment: Still don't understand why but it's working now.
Here's a working example for anyone else that might have issues

https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-example-localstorage-default-buttons?file=src/main.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is correct, I was having issues with my local environment.

Check out https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-example-localstorage-default-buttons?file=src/app/button-toggle-appearance-example.ts